# Docker, running Macos docker image on Windows

Tags: windows, macos, docker

I might be missing something, but is there a docker image that can run MacOS (guest) on a Windows Host.  Like there is for Linux and others ?

I wanted to test MacOS Command Line builds on a live MacOS based system using Docker on a Windows Host

I tried to pull from some MacOS repositories, but got errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do create a MacOS based system in Docker container. In your case, you probably should use a Virtual Machine rather than Docker container.

Docker container need to use the host machine's Linux Kernel, since Mac OS family is Unix-based operating system, currently Docker cannot simulate a Mac OS in Docker container. Here is [a link to explain how container works](https://docs.docker.com/engine/understanding-docker/#/how-does-a-container-work).